# install 21.10 & then upgrade to Kernel 5.16 without going online

Tags: upgrade, kernel

My wifi card only works with 5.16

If I install Ubuntu 21.10 I will not be able to get online until I upgrade the kernel to 5.16 (ethernet is not an option)

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

If there was a way to get a liveISO with 5.16 that would be perfect obviously, but Im not sure thats an option.

Comment: Can you use USB tethering from your mobile phone?

Comment: Great idea! I never knew that was a thing. It IS an option on my Android phone. I will check it out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your phone via USB tethering, and install the kernels using the [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline/) tool.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

[image: mainline]
Image Source: README of the project

Then choose the kernel 5.16 and install it.

---

Alternatively, you can download the kernels and save them in an USB drive.

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.2/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.2-051602-generic_5.16.2-051602.202201200936_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.2/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.2-051602_5.16.2-051602.202201200936_all.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.2/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.2-051602-generic_5.16.2-051602.202201200936_amd64.deb
```

Then connect the USB drive to the newly installed Ubuntu 21.10, and open a terminal in the directory containing the .deb files, and run the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that so clearly.